# Minimum HP for ultralight

Tags: engine, ultralight

What is the minimum HP needed to fly a 200 pound ultralight? I’m looking at a 6.5 HP, 3600 RPM Predator engine, but is that enough?

Comment: Please see the following questions and their answers: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/72021/7532 https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33476/7532 https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/70432/7532 https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45160/7532 https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/74586/7532 https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/68105/7532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a little sketchy, given that commercial ultralights have motors ranging from 15 HP to 120. I’d opt for something within that range. Sure, it might be possible, but you would need an extremely light, aerodynamic craft for that to be a legitimate plane, instead of hovering a few feet off the ground. 15 HP motors would be a better option.